# Formal Language Syntax

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata

Here is the question:

Show that $L = \{0^m1^n : m > 1, n > 1, n < m \}$ is not regular.

I am not sure what superscripts mean in this situation? Does it mean something like this:

$0^5 = 00000$ or $1^7 = 1111111$.

Comment: Your understanding of the meaning of superscripts is correct.

Comment: And once you are ready to solve the question "Show that ... is not regular" look for old items in this Q&A site that mention "pumping lemma". Probably several are linked in the column to the right under "Related".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `0^n` or $0^n$ denotes the string obtained by concatenating $n$ copies of the symbol $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, superscripts mean exactly what you think they do. For your other question (how to use superscripts in SO), there are two ways: use html tags like sup, or use $...$ math.